# threepenny-gui: close the window

Tags: haskell, threepenny-gui

Is it possible to close the window in `threepenny-gui`? I didn't find any Haskell-land functions like that in the package. I also tried `runFunction`s from both `Core` and `Foreign.JavaScript` but failed because neither of the `Window` types is marshable (no `ToJS` instances), and I'd need the window instance to call `close()` on it.

Comment: What does `window` refer to? You should probably add more information to this question.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski `Window` refers to the interface on `threepenny-gui` (specifically, types from the `Foreign.JavaScript` and `Graphics.UI.Threepenny.Core` modules).